# How to get SAP bi report data comma seperated?

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

I want to get the content of a webi report comma separated.

By making GET request to http://localhost:6405/biprws/raylight/v1/documents/6127/reports/1/

with headers

```
accept: text/csv
X-SAP-LogonToken:
```

I am able to get data semi-colon separated

```
<error>
  <error_code>RWS 00058</error_code>
  <message>Not acceptable, (RWS 00058)</message>
</error>
```

But I am trying to get comma-separated values. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify a query parameter in your URL: `columnDelimiter`. Other paramaters can be found [in the online documentation](https://uacp2.hana.ondemand.com/viewer/58f583a7643e48cf944cf554eb961f5b/4.2/en-US/7da1bf3a6f701014aaab767bb0e91070.html).

```
http://localhost:6405/biprws/raylight/v1/documents/6127/reports/1?columnDelimiter=,
```